# Flutter clip png with animation

Tags: animation, flutter

I'm very new to Flutter and I've encountered a problem. I have to clip a png based on a given height value. That works fine with this Class I made:

```
class ScaleClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
    double value;

    @override
    Rect getClip(Size size) {
        Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0 + value, size.width, size.height);
        return rect;
    }

    @override
    bool shouldReclip(ScaleClipper oldClipper) {
        return true;
    }

    ScaleClipper(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now I want to animate the change in the image. I've tried to wrap it in Widgets mentioned here: https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation 
But I didn't get it to work properly. 
This is the widget where I display the image:

```
ClipRect(
            clipper: ScaleClipper(value),
            child: Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30.0, top: 30.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 30.0),
                width: 150.0,
                height: 420.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("images/image.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.contain))),
          ),
```

Do I need the to change my approach to the problem or can I animate the clipping of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer for future newcomers. You can just use a simple Tween animation like this

```
controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
  ..addListener(() {
    setState(() {
      fracturedValue = desiredClipValue * animation.value;
    });
  });
```